# What's the best way to handle member dependencies in OOP?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a `Position` class which represents a stock position like this:

```
class Position {
private:
    double price_;
    double amount_;
    double value_;

public:
    void SetPrice(double price) {
        price_ = price;
    }

    void SetAmount(double amount) {
        amount_ = amount;
    }

    double GetValue() {
        return value_;
    }
...
}
```

The 3 members should satisfy the equation: `price * amount = value`. But each member could be changed from `setter`, maintaining the equation is a problem.

I have 4 different ways to handle this:

1. don't store `value_`, and populate value in `getter` each time when needed:

```
class Position {
private:
    double price_;
    double amount_;
    // double value_;
...

public:
    double GetValue() {
        return price_ * amount_;
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Very clear

Cons:

- The real problem is not just this simple. For example, how should I handle the multiple positions and the `total value` of positions in a class `Portfolio`?
- The `getter` could be time consuming.

2. Calculate `value_` when its dependencies changes

```
class Position {
private:
    double price_;
    double amount_;
    double value_;
...

public:
    void SetPrice(double price) {
        price_ = price;
        value_ = price_ * amount_;
    }

    void SetAmount(double amount) {
        amount_ = amount;
        value_ = price_ * amount_;
    }

    double GetValue() {
        return value_;
    }
}
```

Pros:

- the `getter` will be simple

Cons:

- but all the `setters` will be time consuming,
- and the code much complex that option 1)

3. Use `std::optional` or similar technical, clear `value_` when other members are set.

```
class Position {
private:
    std::optional<double> price_;
    std::optional<double> amount_;
    std::optional<double> value_;
...

public:
    void SetPrice(double price) {
        price_ = price;
        value_.reset();
    }

    void SetAmount(double amount) {
        amount_ = amount;
        value_.reset();
    }

    double GetValue() {
        if (!value_) {
            value_ = price_.value() * amount_.value();
        }
        return value_;
    }
}
```

Pros:

- the `setter` is much clear than option 2)

Cons:

- there are still additional logics in the `setters`

4. Use `make` application like technical, attach `timestamp` onto those members.

```
class TimestampData {
private:
    double value_
    std::time_t time_;

public:
    TimestampData& operator=(double value) {
        value_ = value;
        time_ = std::time(nullptr);
    }
}


class Position {
private:
    TimestampData price_;
    TimestampData amount_;
    TimestampData value_;
...

public:
    void SetPrice(double price) {
        price_ = price;
    }

    void SetAmount(double amount) {
        amount_ = amount;
    }

    double GetValue() {
        if (value_.GetTimestamp() < price_.GetTimestamp()
            || value_.GetTimestamp() < amount_.GetTimestamp()) {
            value_ = price_.GetValue() * amount_.GetValue();
        }
        return value_;
    }
}
```

Pros:

- the `setter` as clear as option 1)

Cons:

- The timestamp tracking could be time consuming

This is just a simple case, I have another class `Portfolio` like this:

```
class Portfolio {
private:
    double valueOfPositions_
    std::map<std::string, Position> positions_
...
}
```

There should be a sync mechanism between `valueOfPositions_` and `positions_`.

What do you call members like `value_` and `valueOfPositions_`? For me they are like `view` members for other members.

What's your best practices to handle this?

Comment: The problem with asking ten C++ developers what are their "best practices to handle <X>" is that you'll get eleven different answers, based on mostly their own opinions rather than facts or citations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Don't you think this a problem? Should there be a design pattern for this kind of problem?

Comment: Maybe java developers think this kind of problems more, but another guy told me I shouldn't add java or c# tag.

Comment: Not everything has a design pattern for it. It is a myth that the way to solve every programming task is to figure out which design pattern to employ for it.

Comment: **Best practice would be to have a function that set both price and amount at once**. But for proposed ways, here is my opinion:
**Prefer #1** if there is not much overhead. Anytime you have duplicate information, there is a chance that something get out of sync (coding error, ignored exceptional cases,...). Otherwise a **variation of #3** but often you need only one optional for the result unless you have to detect incomplete initialisation.

Comment: Also even **if you want a time stamp**, it would be best to have a **read-only object** that receive price and amount. time stamp would be initialised in constructor and as the value is probably used later, it would also be computed in the constructor. That way all objects are always in a valid completely initialized state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you listed 4 ways of handling value in a Position class. I'll ignore the 4th one for a second, because the Timestamp attribute adds another level of complexity (your first 3 options don't have a Timestamp attribute either).

Between the 1st 3 options, the 1st option (simple setters for price and amount, and a getter function for value) is the cleanest, for the very reason you described - it's so clear and simple. (which solution will be easiest to understand after 3 months?)

Going through the cons you described:

- getter will be time-consuming: not really, multiplying price and amount is pretty straightforward computationally, and also in all the other solutions, you still have to do the multiplication anyway, just at different points. Keeping the multiplication simple and contained (only when calling `GetValue()`) means that you can control how often the multiplication is carried out - in your other examples, e.g. in option 2, every time you update price or amount, you do the multiplication one more time.
- how to handle multiple positions and the total value: put all that logic in the `Portfolio` class, or whatever class contains the array of Position objects - initialise a `GetTotalPositionValue()` function. It's much cleaner to have logic for multiple Position objects in whatever data structure holds the Position objects, as opposed to having some of that logic in the Position object itself.

As for adding timestamps, it seems like you'd want a `timestamp` variable for each Position object, and in some other function, e.g. a `GetTotalPositionValueWithinRange()` function, get a subset of your Position objects based on their `timestamp` variable. It also seems like `timestamp` is an attribute of the Position object, on the same level as price and amount - every Position object has a price, amount, value and timestamp.

Hope that answers your question - I'm not always the best at explaining design decisions so I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Maybe, at least for Position class I should just go with option 1 to make life easier. Thanks.